# svnlook author returning author's userid instead of the whole name?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

is there anyway to get the authors full name instead of the userid when using the **svnlook** command in the pre commit hook script in VisualSVN?

Command:

```
for /f %%a in ('svnlook author "%1" -t "%2"') do set USER=%%a
echo %USER% >&2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't full names in default revision|transaction properties in SVN. `svnlook author` will return the same name as shown in `svn log`